# How the atoms of a negatively charged plate of a capacitor accommodate extra electrons?

Tags: electrons, charge, capacitance

Let suppose the capacitor's plates are of aluminium and someone has charged it so that one of the plate is positively charged and the other is negatively charged, also the capacitor is not connected to any e.m.f. source.

Now what I want to understand is that if I separated both plates so that the positively charged plate does attract electrons of the other plate through electric field then how extra electrons are accommodated by the atoms of the negative plate of the capacitor?

Comment: They are accommodated by the solid as extra electrons floating around.

Comment: What makes you think separating the plates will cause the positively charged plate to attract more electrons from the other plate?

Comment: I am confuse where those extra electrons reside in the negatively charged plate. I mean do they reside in the outer most shell of the atoms in the negatively charged plate? if so then does this mean that the applied e.m.f was actually required to insert those electrons in the shells of the atoms?

Comment: @Shuji So are you actually asking how the capacitor gets  charged in the first place?